# VBScript's CopyFile not working

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, filesystemobject

I think it may have something to do with the external file but I am getting the error `Path not found` and don't know why.  Code below.

```
<%

Dim fs
set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CopyFile "http://domain.com/file.xml","softvoyage.xml"
set fs = Nothing

%>DONE.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FileSystemObject is made for local disc files ONLY. Try this:

```
<%
    url = "http://www.espn.com/main.html" 
    set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
    xmlhttp.send "" 
    Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
    set xmlhttp = nothing 
%>
```

Found at http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-read-the-contents-of-a-remote-web-page.html

Comment: "local disc files" or files available over a UNC file share.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the CopyFile method can copy files from http sources. The only examples i've ever seen for the source parameter are for files on the local file system:

```
FileSystemObject.CopyFile "c:\srcFolder\srcFile.txt", "c:\destFolder\"
```

If you need to save data from an http request, check out the [IXMLHTTPRequest object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(VS.85).aspx).